# SalesForce simple login from another website

Tags: salesforce

I have a pretty simple request from a client.  They want a page on their site with a username and password.  They want to put in their sales force username & password into this site, check the login, and if successful, actually redirect them to salesforce already logged in.

Can i just do a simple form post for this, or do I need to use the SOAP or REST API?  Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm doing this from PHP.

Comment: Have you checked whether or not this is acceptable within Salesforce.com's licence terms?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bad idea capturing their credentials elsewhere. I'd suggest using oAuth to do the authentication so that you never need capture the actual salesforce credentials in the other system.

Basically they'd log into the custom site, and if successful you can redirect to salesforce using a full session ID obtained via oAuth - the only catch of course is that they'd have to login to Salesforce themselves upon first login but then after that you could make the Salesforce authentication happen in the background.

Comment: We can't make them login to the salesforce site the first time, if thats what you're getting at.